# How to persist session data in an AngularJS application?

Tags: session, angularjs, cookies

I have this web app written in AngularJs that uses cookies to authenticate the requests in a REST API.

Once the user logs in, the cookie is received and saved in the browser and all subsequent requests send the cookie along to the server. There is a 'User' service/object that saves the isLoggedIn and username values (for UI display/flow). Now, if I refresh the 'index' page, the app restarts. This means that my 'User' object will be cleared. I can check the existence of the cookie and, if it exists, I can re-set the User.isLoggeIn as true and go from there, but I still need to get the username, id, etc. So, my question is: should I create some sort of 'ping' endpoint in the API to verify if a cookie is valid? And if so, the API would send me back the user id and username... OR should I persist the user data in LocalStorage (or some similar cross-browser thing) and just assume the user is logged if the cookie exists? Any other subsequent requests to pages that need authentication would be automatically verified. So, this question really only applies to the scenario where the user refreshes the index page - hence, restarting the web app. I want to know the user data because I want to show a 'user homepage' instead of the 'public homepage'.

What do you think?

Comment: Hi take a look at http://www.espeo.pl/2012/02/26/authentication-in-angularjs-application

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should depend on the server for this. Creating something like `GetCurrentUser` method on the server. If the user is logged on this returns all the properties of the user.

You should even use this server api to get the user data after authentication completes. So the authentication become two step process first the user is authenticated, on success another call is made to server to get current users details.

Using client side local storage for this would not be ideal because you need to do lot of book keeping, in terms of cleaning the logged in user on log out or session expiration.

Also cookies from server would have expiration times an all, and making decision just based on cookie existing on local storage may not be optimal approach.